# How can I reference an unknown in a column the user is uploading to my program?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am a R newbie. I am currently using Rstudio and trying to develop a program that graphs whatever the user gives it (assuming it is a csv file). My problem is, I do not know how to reference the columns in the data that the user is giving. Here is a portion of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

X <- read.csv(file.choose())
print(qplot(data=X, **x=?????, y=?????**, main="la"))
```

For the qplot function (or ggplot2), I want to give an x and y value (columns in the csv). Normally you would just use the `fileName$ColumnName`, but in this case, I don't know what's in the data the user is uploading (so I don't know the column names).

I've tried doing this, without success:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

X <- read.csv(file.choose())
headers <- names(X)
print(qplot(data=X, **x=X$headers[1], y=X$headers[2]**, main="la"))
```

Any ideas guys?

EDIT: I'd also like to be able to display the column name on the graph. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you will always be plotting the first and second columns of the csv, try `x = X[,1]` and `y = X[,2]`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have a reactive function elsewhere that will allow the user to select different columns (1, 2, 3, 4), so is there a way to specify a specific column. Also, do you know a way to actually display the name of the column on the graph?

Comment: @agstudy has the general/flexible solution you are after.

Comment: Why are you doing `X$headers` when you have `headers`? Anyway, those won't work in general as you you need to pass the objects not strings indicating the name of the variable. I thin you may need to switch to `ggplot()` and use the `aes_string()` function as in `mapping = aes_string(....)`

Comment: Thanks Gavin, agstudy was on the exact same mindset as you.

Comment: Here's a sample that sounds similar to what you're doing: https://github.com/jcheng5/seattle-meetup/tree/master/diamonds3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is to use `aes_string` instead of `aes` (I am not sure you know `aes` since you are using `qplot` which use it implicitly). `aes_string` works directly with strings, so this should work:

```
ggplot(data=X)  +
  geom_point(aes_string(x=headers[1], y=headers[2]))
```

Comment: I would have wondered if `aes_string(x=names(X)[1], y=names(X)[2])` would have succeeded without the intermediate construction of `headers`.

Comment: @DWin I wondered also...but without a reproducible example( lazy to create one) I just show the first solution I get.

Comment: Yes, I'm even lazier.